# Deleting a UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiimageview

So what I want to do is if `image1` collides with `image2`, I want to remove `image1` from the screen (not just hide it but remove it) in a way that the application does not crash or use to much memory.

I think it's something related with `release` but I'm not sure. How can I do this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove it from the superview

`[image1 removeFromSuperview];`

EDIT:

if you have a pointer to image1, you might have just added it to the superview and did not release it yet. So, if that is the case and to avoid any leaks, just release it when removing it from superview.

`[image1 removeFromSuperview];
    [image1 release], image1 = nil;`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it from your superview:

```
[image1 removeFromSuperview];
```

If you've managed your memory correctly heretofore, you won't need to release it at this point. Here are a few scenarios:

1. **Your class does *not* own a reference to `image1` (i.e. it's not a property).** So, when you created `image1` and added it to your view, you made sure to autorelease it. As such, the view holds the owning reference; when it is removed from that view, the view will release it.
2. **Your class *does* own a reference to `image1` (i.e. it is a property).** In `-dealloc`, you have released `image1` according to the Objective-C memory management idiom, so when you remove it from the superview, you ***still*** don't need to perform memory management.